# Aluffi Algebra Chapter 0 - Small Categories Doubt

Tags: category-theory

In the bottom image (from Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter 0, page 22 in Preliminaries), he writes that the category corresponding to endowing $\mathbb{Z}$ with the $\leq$ relation is small. Is it small because the objects (which are the integers) are also a set?
[image]

Comment: I remember some categories are too big,which needs to use the notion "class" instead of "set", to avoid some set-theoretical issues.

Answer (score 2):

That's part of it, but not the whole story. A category is *small* if the class of all objects and all morphisms of the category is, in fact, a set. The integers are manifestly a set, but one also needs acknowledge that the morphisms of this category form a set. Given that there's only countably many possible ways to compare two integers, they would form a set, and this category is small.

This notion is not a trivial one: a great many categories of mathematical interest , e.g., $\mathsf{Grp}, \mathsf{Top}, \mathsf{R-Mod}$, are not actually small.

Comment: I see, thank you! However, it seems that Aluffi defines the morphisms from one object to another as a set (he writes, in the definition of categories, "for every two objects A and B, a set Hom_C(A,B) of morphisms"). Is this an error?

Comment: It would be an error, the notion of a category where the homsets are all, in fact, sets, is a "locally small category". This however, is a much more common notion than that of a small category (all the categories I listed are locally small). I haven't finished his text, but I cannot recall him bringing up any non-locally-small category in the book, so I wouldn't sweat it too much.

Comment: @DuncanRamage it’s not an error, just a choice of terminology.

Comment: Fair, but it's certainly a non-standard choice of terminology. Categories for the Working Mathematician and nLab both draw distinctions between "categories" and "locally-small categories".